# How come it is "how come" and not "how comes"? Orig:Is "how come" slang?

Tags: word-usage, slang

Sample Conversation:

> A: How are you?
>
> B: I am mad.
>
> A: How come?

I thought that *how come* was a logical word choice but upon speaking with somebody for whom English is a second language, I found that they did not understand the meaning. I am wondering if using *how come* in this manner is a form of slang.

For some reason saying "How come you are angry?" sounds like bad grammar.

I can imagine the use of "How come, when I talk to you, you are angry?" to be correct with that added phrase in the middle.

So my question is, is using *how come* as in the example conversational slang?
And also is "How come you are angry?" proper English?

Comment: Reminds me of *wherefore*.

Comment: How come you to write thusly?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to rephrase the initial question, which should be something like: How come it is "how come" and not "how comes"? Isn't this the heart of the matter?

Comment: I was about to ask the question myself, but saw that it had been satisfactorily answered, although I think it is not really satisfactorily asked…

Comment: Provide corrections or addendum or alternative ways of asking. Feel free to edit my question, or add a post edit. Really this can be a wiki at this point. @user58319

Comment: B: Your grammar drives me mad.

Comment: I have heard that *how come* is a literal translation of the Dutch *hoekom* and passed into American English via the speech of early Dutch settlers. So it may not ever have been grammatically analyzed, and is "fossilized" in that form even though it is a little atypical for English. I need to find a source for that though.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Looking in [COCA](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/?c=coca&q=11382032), *how come* is very common in American English. It's used to mean *why*, in questions, and occasionally in statements:

> **How come** the reporters aren't asking that?
> And that's **how come** this song "This Land Is Your Land" became known throughout America.

If we break down the places it appears, a pattern emerges: *how come* is almost never used where formal writing is demanded, as in academic writing, but is frequently used where informality is okay, as in fiction dialogue and speech:

```
           TOTAL    SPOKEN  FICTION  MAGAZINE  NEWSPAPER   ACADEMIC
HOW COME   2689     882     1318     283       164         42
```

In American English, at least, *how come?* is informal, but probably not considered slang.

Comment: That is a cool site, I will show all my foreign friends, I'll be more confident giving them answers when they ask me specific questions hehe. Thank you for all your research :)

Comment: It's also fairly common in AuE.

Comment: It's also common in BrE. IME its usage is not identical to that of "why": "why" is more "for what reason" and "how come" is more "from what cause", though I admit there's some overlap.

Comment: To me "How come?" implies surprise or complicity, whereas "Why?" sound neutral and serious. "How come you aren't in class?" vs "Why aren't you in class?".

Answer (score 14):

I would guess that "How come?" is simply a shortening of "How does it come to be (that)?".

Some digging finds the quotation in the 16th century [Foxe's Book of Martyrs XII](http://www.ccel.org/f/foxe/martyrs/fox112.htm)

> After this, Tyndale corrected the same New Testaments again, and
>   caused them to be newly imprinted, so that they came thick and
>   threefold over into England. When the bishop perceived that, he sent
>   for Packington, and said to him, "**How cometh this**, that there are so
>   many New Testaments abroad? You promised me that you would buy them
>   all."

Comment: This sounds interesting--do you have any further information on this?

Comment: "How does it come to be ..." I would not have found this on my own but this makes a lot of sense. Thank you I might add this strange structure into my vocabulary haha. :)

Comment: Don't you rather think "how come" stands for "how has it come about that… (then mentioning a present state of things)" since the idea of present result is obviously what the person asking the question has in mind. Not that is makes a big difference, but I feel "come" is more probably a past participle on its own than a bare infinitive…

Comment: @user58319: I suspect It was all present: *How cometh ...? * to *How comes ...?* and then a set phrase of *How come?*, perhaps with a past of *How came ...?* which is now rarely used.

Answer (score 2):

> So my question is, is using *how come* in the example conversational slang?

Yes, it is part of spoken speech, but very rarely in written speech.

> And also, is "How come you are angry?"  proper english?

No, "how come" is not proper English. It's colloquial, or informal. The actual phrase is "how came", as in:

> How came you to be so angry?

But that sounds very archaic. [Other possible origins](http://grammar.quickanddirtytips.com/is-how-come-proper-english.aspx) are "How comes it to be..." or "How did it come about?"

The normal way to ask a question is "Why?"

> A: How are you?
>   B: I am mad.
>   A: Why?
>   B: ...

Comment: Colloquial that helps me alot thank you :) Thank you for the article.

Answer (score 2):

It's not even that unique. In German it's not uncommon to say and write: "Wie kommt es, dass..."
Literally in English: "How comes it, that..."
So, to my 'native german ears' the "how come" actually sounds proper. I remember that it just appeared/felt a little short, like incomplete (thus confusing or funny) to me, when I heard it the first time.